# Why Innodb's Innodb_dblwr_pages_written not equals Innodb_pages_written?

Tags: mysql

It says Mysql innodb's "Innodb_dblwr_pages_written" always equals to "Innodb_pages_written", but it doesn't look like it. Why?

Mysql version:

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.17    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My doublewrite is open:

```
mysql> show global variables like '%innodb_doublewrite%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| innodb_doublewrite | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

values as follows:

```
mysql> show status like '%Innodb_dblwr_pages_written%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written | 2     |
+----------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show status like '%Innodb_pages_written%';
+----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name        | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| Innodb_pages_written | 46    |
+----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show status like '%innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed%';
+----------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                    | Value |
+----------------------------------+-------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed | 46    |
+----------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

reference:
[image]

Comment: 1) what does say that these two counters should always have the same value? 2) if these counters should always have the same value, then why would mysql have two counters instead of one? 3) why does this matter?

Comment: *It says Mysql innodb's "Innodb_dblwr_pages_written" always equals to "Innodb_pages_written"*  -- Where does it says this ? Can you quote the reference link also in the question.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya A Chinese book named "MySQL技术内幕：InnoDB存储引擎-姜承尧.pdf"

Comment: @Shadow 1)when innodb open doublewrite, each write dirty page to disk triggers one double write, so these two values should be the same.

Comment: Well, the actual counter values suggest that you are missing something - perhaps not all flushes go through the double buffer. I'm afraid you need to check mysql's source code and find out when these counters are increased to get a defìnitive answer. If this difference does not cause any problems with developing a software you are working on, then your question really belongs to the dba sister dite of SO, not here.

Comment: @Shadow em... This does not case any problem, you are right, maybe I miss sth.. thanks a lot.